# How to generate XML data of selected records and vice versa in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How to return select statement records as XML data and in other function how to read that XML data and give output as normal select records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method for generating XML is probably this:

```
select xmltype('select a,b,c from my_table').getClobVal() from dual
```

The XML you get will be in a generic Oracle format. If you want it in a custom format you will have to transform it using e.g. XMLTYPE.transform with an XSLT tranformation. This is not exactly simple - you will have to google for some tutorials.

The other way around you can use XMLTABLE. There are many ways to do it - basically something like:

```
select x.*
from   xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW' passing "data"
          columns Column1 varchar2(10) path 'Column1',
                  Column2 varchar2(50) path 'Column2' ) x;
```

In the example "data" could be e.g.:

```
XMLTYPE('<ROWSET><ROW><Column1>abc</Column1><Column2>efg</Column2></ROW></ROWSET>')
```

which is how the generic Oracle xml format looks like. You can use XMLTABLE with any xml format though.

There is a lot of additional features to xmltable - you should look for documentation or tutorials.

Comment: Thanks Jens. I can now generate XML and read it back. I have posed the complete procedure and function which can do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    --To return selected data as XML
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "HR"."F_DETAILS_IN_XML"(EMP_ID VARCHAR2,
  DEPT_ID VARCHAR2)
return XMLTYPE
IS
XMLDOC XMLTYPE;
result   clob;
begin
  select DBMS_XMLGEN.getxml('select
    EMPLOYEE_ID,
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    EMAIL,
    PHONE_NUMBER,
    HIRE_DATE,
    JOB_ID,
    department_id
    FROM EMPLOYEES 
    where 
    employee_id = '''||EMP_ID|| '''or department_id = '''||DEPT_ID||'''') INTO result 
    FROM DUAL;        
    xmldoc := xmltype(result);
   return XMLDOC;
END;
/
```

This procedure will display the result from XML

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "HR"."DETAILS_FROM_XML"(EMP_ID VARCHAR2,
  DEPT_ID VARCHAR2)
  AS
  V_XML XMLTYPE;
  v_employee_id    VARCHAR2(20) ;
  V_FIRST_NAME     VARCHAR2(20) ;
  V_LAST_NAME      VARCHAR2(25) ;
  V_EMAIL          VARCHAR2(25) ;
  V_PHONE_NUMBER   VARCHAR2(20) ;  
  V_JOB_ID         VARCHAR2(10) ;
  V_DEPARTMENT_ID  NUMBER(4);
  v_count NUMBER(8) := 1;
  BEGIN 
  v_XML := F_DETAILS_IN_XML(EMP_ID, DEPT_ID); 

  WHILE V_XML.existsNode('//ROW[' || v_count || ']') = 1 LOOP
dbms_output.put_line('Record Number := '|| v_count);
dbms_output.put_line('EMPLOYEE_ID '||v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/EMPLOYEE_ID/text()').getStringVal());
dbms_output.put_line('FIRST_NAME '||v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/FIRST_NAME/text()').getStringVal());
dbms_output.put_line('LAST_NAME '||v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/LAST_NAME/text()').getStringVal());
dbms_output.put_line('EMAIL '||v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/EMAIL/text()').getStringVal());
dbms_output.put_line('PHONE_NUMBER '||v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/PHONE_NUMBER/text()').getStringVal());
dbms_output.put_line('HIRE_DATE '||v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/HIRE_DATE/text()').getStringVal());
dbms_output.put_line('JOB_ID '||v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/JOB_ID/text()').getStringVal());
dbms_output.put_line('DEPARTMENT_ID'|| v_XML.extract('//ROW[' || v_count || ']/DEPARTMENT_ID/text()').getStringVal());
v_count := v_count + 1;
  END LOOP;  
      END;
/
```

Comment: Yes - That's another way of doing it. But I got the impression that you wanted to be able to read back the XML as if it was a table - producing a query result. For that purpose I would still recommend XMLTABLE. Anyway - if you found my answer useful I would appreciate if you flagged it as correct by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer:-)